How does ngrok detect request cancellation
I have a local server with an endpoint that simply returns 200 after a 10 seconds delay
I’m exposing the endpoint through ngrok
Im sending a request via postman
In postman if I click cancel while sending the request, ngrok never receives a response even after the server responds
How does this work
Since I sent a request with postman the server process the response regardless of cancellation which I expect
I also would expect ngrok to than receive a response but it doesn’t it just says waiting for response from server as if it was aware of the cancellation
Does cancellation on postman do anything more than ignore response?

Hi! ngrok employee here.
ngrok tries to work as a transparent reverse-proxy, so until the TCP connection closes, we should be transparently passing things through to what's behind your tunnel. (Unless you have any edge modules set up.)
A couple questions to understand your question...

When you say "ngrok never receives a response" can you clarify how you tested this or what you see?
Are there docs for the Postman cancellation? I looked and couldn't find anything. My guess is it just closes the TCP connection, which would close the connection on ngrok's side as well.


Hi thank you for answering I created a request with C# and simply passed a cancellation token with a timeout value and it had the same effect I think what’s happening is that the client is sending an RST signal I tested just by looking that the web interface of ngrok

The web interfaces just keeps saying that it is waiting for response from server this makes sense now if ngrok is affected by closing the TCP connection
